# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 27 Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql, i just want to ask what's wrong with this code.

```
DECLARE @Id as BIGINT;
SET @Id = CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 103), '/', '') + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 108), ':', '') AS BIGINT);
```

Comment: try yours qry's separately: SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 103), '/', '')   and check results

Comment: @Mate I tried, and it works, but whats wrong with the code. It works before but now it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175055(v=sql.105).aspx):

> The char data type is a fixed-length data type when the NOT NULL clause is specified. If a value shorter than the length of the column is inserted into a char NOT NULL column, the value is right-padded with blanks to the size of the column. For example, if a column is defined as char(10) and the data to be stored is "music", SQL Server stores this data as "music_____", where "_" indicates a blank space.

Try using varchar and also try mentioning exact size irrespective of char/varchar

```
DECLARE @Id as BIGINT;
SElect @Id =   REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '') +   REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
print @id
```

Your char is having some blank spaces at the end.so you are seeing the error..if you want to use char,you have to replace spaces like below..

```
DECLARE @Id as BIGINT;
set @Id =   replace( REPLACE(CONVERT(char(20), GETDATE(), 103), '/', ''),' ','') +    replace(REPLACE(CONVERT(char(20), GETDATE(), 108), ':', ''),' ','')
print @id
```